# What is the most secure and efficient way to order app.use() functions?

Tags: node.js, express, security, networking, request

I have code in my Node app that defines how static resources should be served with added security by helmet middleware and HTTPS redirection. And I added compression for efficiency. And I use some cookies.

But what is the best way to order these functions? Or doesn't it matter at all? I cannot seem to find documentation on this topic.

(general variables)

(app.set code)

```
...

// Security

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.cspNonce = nonce;
    next();
});

app.use(helmet());

// CSP

app.use(
    helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
        directives: {
            //some directives
        }
    })
    );

app.use(
    helmet.expectCt({
        //some options
    })
    );

// Compress requests

app.use(compression());

// HTTPS redirection

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if(!req.secure) {
        return res.redirect(301, ['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join(''));
    }
    next();
});

// Cookies

app.use(cookieParser('String'));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    let cookie = req.cookies.cookieName;
    if (cookie === undefined) {
        let randomNumber=Math.random().toString();
        //some more logic
        res.cookie('session', randomNumber, cookieConfig);
    };
    next();
});

// Static resources

const options = {
    //some options
    }
};

app.use(express.static('public', options));

...
```

(routing)

(server start)